# Paginate the request data from a pexel api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, backend

This is my node, express app.

**app.js file**

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const site = {
        url : "https://api.pexels.com/videos/search?query=nature&page=1&per_page=8",
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'YOUR API KEY'
        } 
     }
     request(site, (error, response, body) => {
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            const data = JSON.parse(body);
            res.render("index", {data: data});
        }
     });
});
```

**index.ejs file**

```
<section id="about">
    <button>Show More</button>
</section>
```

I want to know how I increase page no to show more videos using show more button in index.ejs file.
please help me with this issue.

Comment: On documentation:

https://www.pexels.com/api/documentation/#videos-search

increase `per_page` max 80

Comment: But I want to change the page number when I click on show more button. Is there any way to change it.